# Fan error during boot but it boots well

Tags: boot, 64bit, uefi

I installed the second linux distro along with Ubuntu, something went wrong, it was to choosing a wrong nvidia driver, and I decided to remove that distro completely by deleting the partition and creating it again (I'll persist installing it) from Ubuntu. However, I had (after the installation the 2nd distro) and am having (after I've removed it) an issue:

during boot there 2 beeps and the label "Fan error" on the black screen before the boot menu appears. It does boot well (Ubuntu) but that error slows down the boot and it generally not normal. I tried boot-repair but the error has remained up til now.

I'm on x64 system and UEFI.

Comment: That sounds like a hardware problem being reported by your BIOS.  If so, it's nothing to do with Linux.

Comment: If the error message occurs before the OS tries to load, then it has nothing to do with the OS. So, sounds like you have a bad fan somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments this is a BIOS error. The issue is probably caused by an empty CMOS battery. If the battery is empty the measurement of the fan speed fails which results in a fan error.

Of course it may be, that your fan actually fails or that there is a failure within your main board.

There are some other suggestions here: http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f108/resolved-fan-error-ibm-152396.html

Comment: so it's not related to ubuntu and another distro in any way?

Comment: No. This is only hardware/BIOS/UEFI related. Either your driver messed up the fan or this is just random.